# Is prophecy impossible now?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, nevua-prophecy, golus-exile

According to [SimpleToRemember.com](http://www.simpletoremember.com/articles/a/jewsandjesus/) (also known as Judaism online), prophecy is only possible if the majority of the Jewish people are living in Israel:

> Prophecy can only exist in Israel when the land is inhabited by a majority of world Jewry. During the time of Ezra (circa 300 BCE), when the majority of Jews refused to move from Babylon to Israel, prophecy ended upon the death of the last prophets—Haggai, Zechariah and Malachi.

Is this the widespread opinion on the subject?  What is the scriptural basis for this idea?  Does this mean that prophecy was impossible during the Babylonian Captivity?

Comment: Though I am not a Jew, but I know that during the Babylonisn exile there was some prophets especially Daniel the prophet.

Comment: @mil you should probably take a read at this http://www.jewfaq.org/prophet.htm

Comment: @Wad Cheber I assume you are looking for something beyond the talmudic statement  משמתו נביאים האחרונים חגי זכריה ומלאכי נסתלקה רוח הקודש מישראל

Comment: @Danno I'm looking for whatever you can give me, but I don't know how to read Hebrew.

Comment: @Danno I always wondered why his book wasn't among the prophets' books but in the Ketuvim section. I never knew that.

Comment: @WadCheber The talmud states explicitly that "from when the final prophets, Chagai, Zechariah and Malachi died, the ru'ach hakodesh departed from Israel."

Comment: @Danno - I looked it up - "ru'ach hakodesh" means "spirit of G-d", specifically as it relates to prophecy and spiritual wisdom?

Comment: http://www.ypt.co.il/eng/tora_show.asp?mador=&id=51187 @WadCheber

Comment: I advise closing this question as only YHWH can answer.

Comment: No https://youtu.be/QOFM-oM1VGg&t=15m25s